# Azure ADAL for Python - facing issue with acquire_token_with_username_password method

Tags: python, azure, adal, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to retrieve access token using azure user id and password .
Initially I tried with the following python code block

```
import adal
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    "https://management.azure.com/",
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET)
```

This is returning the token without any issue .
I am following an example from https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python for retrieving the token using username and password and the code block is the the following

```
token2 = context.acquire_token_with_username_password("https://management.azure.com/",USER_NAME,PASSWORD,CLIENT_ID)
```

In this case ,no token is returned , instead following response is returned .

```
File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 145, in acquire_token_with_username_password
    return self._acquire_token(token_func)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 109, in _acquire_token
    return token_func(self)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 143, in token_func
    return token_request.get_token_with_username_password(username, password)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 286, in get_token_with_username_password
    token = self._get_token_username_password_federated(username, password)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 252, in _get_token_username_password_federated
    username, password)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 211, in _perform_username_password_for_access_token_exchange
    username, password)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 198, in _perform_wstrust_exchange
    result = wstrust.acquire_token(username, password)
  File "F:\All_Python\Python_Setup\Python27\lib\site-packages\adal\wstrust_request.py", line 160, in acquire_token
    raise AdalError(return_error_string, error_response)
adal.adal_error.AdalError: WS-Trust RST request returned http error: 500 and server response: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2017-06-07T12:12:56.567Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2017-06-07T12:17:56.567Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If anybody has any idea on this, please let me know .

Comment: On public Azure using username/password your AUTHORITY could be "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common". Could you otherwise share your Authority? Also RESOURCE should "https://management.core.windows.net/"

Comment: @LaurentMazuel The resource `https://management.core.windows.net` is for Azure Service Management, and the resource `https://management.azure.com` is for Azure Resource Management.

Comment: Tokens issued for management.core.windows.net are also good for management.azure.com. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information of error stack, per my experience, due to the error comes from the method `_get_token_username_password_federated` and 500 error code for WS-Trust RST request, it seems that the user/password you used for acquiring token not created in the Azure AD of your app registed, but looks like that created in a federated AD.

Please try to do the two ways below for inspection the issue.

1. Create a new user in the Azure AD of your app registed on Azure portal with your admin accout, then use the new user/password for retrieving the token.
2. Inspect your Azure AD configuration to make sure whether deployed Active Directory Federation Services and the current use/password created in a federated AD instance.